# Windows 8.1 and windows 10 app issues

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have a few questions which i need to be clear on before i do windows 10 development.

1.Will 8.1 app work in windows 10 os(both phone and pc)

2.Is it possible to port 8.1 app (store app) to 10 app through command line. If yes,please explain how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes windows 8.1 app will work just fine on windows 10.
2. Porting is possible from windows 8.1 to windows 10 as there are API changes so you code can brake. for details how you can port windows 8.1 to windows 10 watch [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/A-Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10/21) video

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

yes it will work fine. the repository API,s of the Windows 10 might be different but a few changes to them can work very fine.